# Only rendering the Google login button on one page

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue where the google login button is rendering on every page because its "hardcoded" into the html file (or so I think is the root cause)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="....apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
        <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

I generate the button with LoginPage.js

```
/* global gapi */

import React from 'react';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router';


class SignIn extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onSignIn = this.onSignIn.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('this mounted')
        gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
            'scope': 'profile email',
            'width': 300,
            'height': 50,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'dark',
            'onsuccess': this.onSignIn,
        });
    }


    onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
        // want to add in a redirect to `/options`
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div id="my-signin2" data-onsuccess={this.onSignIn}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default withRouter(SignIn)
```

Finally I have another component page called `Form` (that I'm not going to show all of the JS for simplicity sake).

Then my index.js

```
const App = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path="/" component={SignIn} />
                <Route path="/options" component={Form} />       
            </div>
        </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm having an issue that the Google SignIn button is being rendered on every page.

Is there something I need to change in my HTML file? Is it because it's being fired when `componentDidMount()` is being run?

Or is it because I am using react-router incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your router. If you only want the sign In component to show up on '/' then you need to specify an exact match:

`<Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />`

Comment: ahhhh I see. Yea, that was it. Didn't realize it was matching "/" with "/options"